# Don't destroy contents of Bootstrap Popover when hidden

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a `<select>` element in a Twitter Bootstrap Popover. If I change the selected item and hide the popover, the next time I show the popover **the value has been reset**. My understanding is that the Bootstrap Popover destroys the contents when it is hidden. **How can I "persist" the contents of a popover, so the selected values "stick"?**

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/STHWA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Twitter Bootstrap's Popover doesn't have the necessary events, I ended up going with [PowerTip](https://github.com/stevenbenner/jquery-powertip) and [was able to solve this](http://jsfiddle.net/UWzvm/) using PowerTip's events.